# Facebook APIs, Friends permission, rationale and limitations

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Looking at this page

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/
```

it seems that a Facebook users can allow an application to access pretty much everything about their friends (including notes and photos); this seems really strange to me and I am wondering if there is any limitation. If user A decides to share some pictures just with his close friends and one of this close friend (user B) uses the App XYZ that requires friends_photos permissions, pictures of user A at some point can be viewable by all the user of the App XYZ.
Is this exactly what happens or there is any kind of limitation?

You might say that user B could anyway publish the pictures of user A, for example on flickr, even without using the app XYZ but I think the case is very different, if there is a third-party between, the risk of loosing the control on the content is much higher.

Comment: Every user can specify in their settings what data they want to share with apps that friends are using (apart from the public basic info, if you don’t want even that to share, then you have to disable apps at all – which means even you yourself can not use any apps any more).

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that. Do you know which are the default settings? In my case, almost everything is unchecked even if I don't think I never properly configured these permissions (maybe I just don't remember).

Comment: The defaults are to allow everything I think – c’mon, it’s Facebook after all :-)